# Using shoulda matchers to test `allow_nil` in combination with `uniqueness` and `scope`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, shoulda

I'm building an ActiveRecord model for a table that stores key/value pairs

Example -

```
|------------------------------|
| KEY      | VALUE             |
|----------|-------------------|
| LOCATION | San Francisco, CA |
| TITLE    | Manager           |
| LOCATION | New York City, NY |
|------------------------------|
```

Here's the model -

```
class CompanyEnum < ActiveRecord::Base
  KEYS = [:title, :department, :location]
  KEYS_ENUM = KEYS.map(&:to_s).map(&:upcase)

  # `key` column must be one of the above - LOCATION, DEPARTMENT, or TITLE
  validates(:key, inclusion: KEYS_ENUM, allow_nil: false)

  # `value` can be anything, but must be unique for a given key (ignoring case) 
  validates(
    :value,
    uniqueness: { scope: :key, case_sensitive: false },
    allow_nil: false
  )
end
```

I'm using the [shoulda matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) to write specs for these validations. So in my spec file I have the following two specs -

```
describe "validations" do
  it { should_not allow_value(nil).for(:key) }
  it { should_not allow_value(nil).for(:value) }
end
```

My problem is that the 1st validation for `:key` passes, but the 2nd validation for `:value` fails. As per the model definition, both use the same `allow_nil: false` option.

```
1) CompanyEnum validations value should not allow value to be set to nil
   Failure/Error: it { should_not allow_value(nil).for(:value) }
     Expected errors when value is set to nil,
     got no errors
   # ./spec/models/company_enum_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/support/analytics.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is there any logical issue with using `allow_nil: false` with `uniqueness:` and the `scope:` optoins? Or is it anything related to me naming the actual columns `:key` and `:value` (since those seem generic enough to conflict with some other methods) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a presence validator? I think it messes up because of the scope clause. Also just a performance mention but you might want to freeze each string and the array for the keys enum otherwise they are created with each model instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allow_nil: false` on your uniqueness validation doesn't mean that `nil` is not an allowed value. It's a little misleading.

As you may know already, by default, the uniqueness validation works this way (judging by the code you're using):

- If there are two records with the same value of `key` and `value`, then the second record should be invalid compared to the first (provided the first exists in the database).
- If there are two records with different values of `key` and `value`, then both records should be valid.

So what does `allow_nil` do? Let's see what [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) have to say:

> `:allow_nil` - If set to `true`, skips this validation if the attribute is `nil` (default is `false`).

So if true, `allow_nil` allows two records to co-exist with `nil` values for the attribute that is being validated (in this case `value`).

But you've specified `allow_nil: false`, which means this option doesn't apply anyway.

In summary, your first usage of `allow_value` fails because `nil` is not a valid value for `key` (the inclusion validation fails). The second usage passes, however, because `nil` is a valid value for `value` (provided there are no existing records that also have a `value` of `nil`).

My point, I guess, is that if you really want to test your validations, you should use the matchers that correspond directly to these validations:

```
it do
  should validate_inclusion_of(:key).
    in_array(["TITLE", "DEPARTMENT", "LOCATION"]).
    allow_nil
end

it do
  should validate_uniqueness_of(:value).
    scoped_to(:key).
    case_insensitive
end
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! I guess the purpose of `allow_nil` is not to describe the value of the field, but to flag weather the validation itself should run for `nil` values. Seems a bit misleading as you mentioned, but thanks for clearing it up